# Could the ELU experts please look at this question at ELL?

Tags: discussion

An Academia participant felt daunted by ELU and requested that a question be posted at ELL instead of ELU.  But the question is not getting enough attention there despite a good-sized bounty.

Pretty please, you smart ELU folks, take a look, I need your help in figuring this out. https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/155543/18523

Comment: There are plenty of answers posted for that question. What seems to be the sticking issue?

Comment: If you would like it migrated I think we can do that for you. While I think it’s kind that you took someone else’s wishes into account, it’s your question and you should feel free to ask it on the site that will get you the sort of answer you want. If that doesn’t help Massimo with the sort of answer he would like, he should ask his own question focused on his interest. Just flag for the mod team and one of us can refund the bounty and migrate it.

Comment: @ColleenV - Boy that's a tough decision.  I was trying very hard to accommodate his preference.  I know what it's like to try to function in a language that's not my own and that isn't even a strong language for me.  (I lived in Denmark for several years, France for several years, and visited Germany a lot.  And when I first got to Mexico my Spanish was nonexistent and then very much in development for some time.  He was already extremely offended by my edit and I don't want to make it worse.  I have valued him as a colleague so to speak on Academia.

Comment: @Lawrence - Yours is the highest-voted answer (4, compared to 11 for the question).  Judging from the numbers others might be having as much trouble as I am figuring out whether you're saying yes or no.

Comment: @aparente001 That's not my answer. It belongs to someone with a similar username - but with an extra letter ("C") tacked onto the end. I have a tentative answer in mind, but haven't got around to fully posting it. But the question itself seems to have grown - can you summarise what you're looking for that's not yet in the answers?

Comment: @Lawrence - Oops. // Is what the author wrote correct or not?

Comment: Well, it seems to me that the question about the dispute is already answered - Massimo agrees that it isn't the most idiomatic way to say it and is OK with that because it is a little wordplay joke to him (as someone who amuses myself with odd turns of phrase that no-one else ever seems to "get", I empathize :) ) .  Your interest in the question seems deeper than that, so an alternative might be to ask a follow-up question here with a link to the ELL question as context.

Comment: @ColleenV - The only Oxford definition I could find that *might* fit would be 4b.  Now there are two ways of reasoning -- one, just go by the text of the definition --> then the author's use of "recite" was correct; two, use the examples given to understand definition 4b fully --> then the author's context does not fit within 4b and his use of "recite" was incorrect.  What's your opinion?

Comment: @aparente001 I think that dictionaries, even those as authoritative as OED, don't completely encompass correct usage. There are plenty of credible examples of "the notice recites" in legal text, so I'm fine with it being an extremely formal/archaic but grammatically correct construct. It's not idiomatic but if it is amusing to the author and it communicates what was intended (even if it sounds weird) why are we debating it? The question after this point really is more suitable for EL&U in my opinion because it's not about pragmatic usage.

Comment: Hi @aparente001, perhaps it's a failure on my part to communicate, but I've asked several times what the problem is with the existing answers, and I don't think you've told me yet what it is. I might have something to contribute, but I'd like to know what the real problem is first. So ... what is the problem with the many existing answers on the ELL question? Or put another way: why aren't you satisfied with the existing answers? That's *not* a rhetorical question. I'm asking for information.

Comment: @Lawrence - Not your fault.  Sometimes it's hard to explain what you don't understand when you don't understand.  But it's all over now and here's what I got: The author was purposefully trying to sound legalistic.  Which I would still fix if I were his editor, because I think there are better ways to convey that attitude.  But it doesn't matter at Academia.  Academia is a very international place where all communication is rather approximate, and, as my monolingual German-speaking late father-in-law, bless him, used to say, we sometimes have to resort to talking with hands and feet.

Comment: Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 7):

That question would be on topic on ELU (although the edits should not really be identified like that: meld the information into the question, where the edit history shows what has happened to it). I don't think I'd object if it were migrated over here.

If you "need our help" then the question is better here than there, but if the ELL community feels it's on topic there and wants to keep it, that's fine too.